# Chat privilege update

Tags: feature-request, chat

If I am not mistaken, you must have 75+ reputation in order to use the chat. If I try to chat with someone without the rep requirement it says that I can't. I thought it could be usful if a user that have the needed reputation could initiate a chat with anyone. It's espacially good if the user that have wrote the qeustion in the first place is new.

Comment: [You need 20 reputation](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/chat) to  be able to participate in chat.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I was confued between chat rooms privilege and the chat itself, but my suggestion is still relevant. Many 1-rep users ask questions.

Comment: Yes, I agree it would be useful to have. It's been requested before, but not implemented.

Comment: ...so, you are basically saying that it would be implemented at all?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand. It will be implemented if Stack Exchange thinks it's a viable suggestion and worth the effort. It's also been asked on [metase], here: [Invite low rep users to participate in chat](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100291/invite-low-rep-users-to-participate-in-chat) – but has not yet been declined or marked as planned, so you can basically just wait.

Comment: Ok, sorry, I didn't actually know how this works, the implemetation of new fetures. I thought that the staff forwards good suggestions to the dev team or something.

Comment: There's sort of an overlap between staff and dev team :) Stack Exchange *does* monitor feature requests and bug reports, but we moderators unfortunately can't really decide anything about what (or when) features are implemented.